# Connect to remote Ubuntu Server GUI

Tags: networking, server, ssh, webserver

I have a server running remotely by ip address `5.231.XX.XXX` running Ubuntu 13.10 Operating system.
I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop.

I am able to connect to my server via terminal by ssh login as:

```
ssh root@5.231.XX.XXX
```

I am also able to connect via nautilus and open its folders.

I have also installed GUI Interface on my server by using commands via ssh login

```
# sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Now, how could I be able to connect and view my server remotely with GUI Interface.

Answer (score 9):

You can use vnc for gui access to server.

Install the VNC-server

```
apt-get install vnc4server
```

Please make sure that you are using only vnc-server & no other VNC-server are installed as this could give errors in future mostly that clipboard sharing between the host Ubuntu Server & vnc-client machine. You can check it as follows:

```
xxx@yyy ~ $ sudo dpkg -l | grep vnc
ii  vnc4server                                            4.1.1+xorg4.3.0-37ubuntu5                           amd64        Virtual network computing server software
xxx@yyy ~ $
```

Please uninstall if tightvnc or anything similar installed.
Adding VNC user

In my case I am using user=sssss it will differ in your case. You can use any username for the same.

```
adduser sssss

xxx@server1:~$ sudo adduser sssss
Adding user `sssss' ...
Adding new group `sssss' (1001) ...
Adding new group `sssss' (1001) ...
Adding new user `sssss' (1001) with group `sssss' ...
Creating home directory `/home/sssss' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...

Enter new UNIX password: <--yourpassword
Retype new UNIX password: <--yourpassword
passwd: password updated successfully
Changing the user information for sssss
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
    Full Name []: <--ENTER
    Room Number []: <--ENTER 
    Work Phone []:<--ENTER 
    Home Phone []:<--ENTER
    Other []:<--ENTER 
Is the information correct? [Y/n]<--ENTER
```

Start the vncserver with the user, for this use:

```
su - srijan
vncserver
```

It will see:

```
sssss@server1:~$ vncserver

You will require a password to access your desktops.

Password:<--Put your VNC password 
Verify:<--Put your VNC password
Password too long - only the first 8 characters will be used
xauth:  file /home/sssss/.Xauthority does not exist

New 'server1:1 (sssss)' desktop is server1:1

Creating default startup script /home/sssss/.vnc/xstartup
Starting applications specified in /home/sssss/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/sssss/.vnc/server1:1.log

sssss@server1:~$
```

Make backup of the original file & then make the configuration

```
cp ~/.vnc/xstartup ~/.vnc/xstartup.bak > ~/.vnc/xstartup
vi ~/.vnc/xstartup

#!/bin/sh
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
startxfce4 &

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
```

Make the startup script for the vncserver

```
sudo vi /etc/init.d/vncserver


#!/bin/bash

unset VNCSERVERARGS
VNCSERVERS=""
[ -f /etc/vncserver/vncservers.conf ] && . /etc/vncserver/vncservers.conf
prog=$"VNC server"
start() {
 . /lib/lsb/init-functions
 REQ_USER=$2
 echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
 ulimit -S -c 0 >/dev/null 2>&1
 RETVAL=0
 for display in ${VNCSERVERS}
 do
 export USER="${display##*:}"
 if test -z "${REQ_USER}" -o "${REQ_USER}" == ${USER} ; then
 echo -n "${display} "
 unset BASH_ENV ENV
 DISP="${display%%:*}"
 export VNCUSERARGS="${VNCSERVERARGS[${DISP}]}"
 su ${USER} -c "cd ~${USER} && [ -f .vnc/passwd ] && vncserver :${DISP} ${VNCUSERARGS}"
 fi
 done
}
stop() {
 . /lib/lsb/init-functions
 REQ_USER=$2
 echo -n $"Shutting down VNCServer: "
 for display in ${VNCSERVERS}
 do
 export USER="${display##*:}"
 if test -z "${REQ_USER}" -o "${REQ_USER}" == ${USER} ; then
 echo -n "${display} "
 unset BASH_ENV ENV
 export USER="${display##*:}"
 su ${USER} -c "vncserver -kill :${display%%:*}" >/dev/null 2>&1
 fi
 done
 echo -e "\n"
 echo "VNCServer Stopped"
}
case "$1" in
start)
start $@
;;
stop)
stop $@
;;
restart|reload)
stop $@
sleep 3
start $@
;;
condrestart)
if [ -f /var/lock/subsys/vncserver ]; then
stop $@
sleep 3
start $@
fi
;;
status)
status Xvnc
;;
*)
echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|condrestart|status}"
exit 1
esac
```

Make it executable:

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/vncserver
```

Make the configuration file for the vncserver  by creating file as follows:

```
mkdir -p /etc/vncserver
vi /etc/vncserver/vncservers.conf
```

Give the entries like this.

```
VNCSERVERS="1:sssss"
VNCSERVERARGS[1]="-geometry 1024x768"
```

Add it into boot startups:

```
update-rc.d vncserver defaults 99

xxx@server1:~$ sudo update-rc.d vncserver defaults 99
 Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/vncserver ...
   /etc/rc0.d/K99vncserver -> ../init.d/vncserver
   /etc/rc1.d/K99vncserver -> ../init.d/vncserver
   /etc/rc6.d/K99vncserver -> ../init.d/vncserver
   /etc/rc2.d/S99vncserver -> ../init.d/vncserver
   /etc/rc3.d/S99vncserver -> ../init.d/vncserver
   /etc/rc4.d/S99vncserver -> ../init.d/vncserver
   /etc/rc5.d/S99vncserver -> ../init.d/vncserver
xxx@server1:~$
```

Reboot the machine.

To access server you can user any `vnc` client app, list is [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Clients)

Comment: Wow!  Good one!  (and an upvote!)

Answer (score 0):

Before beginning, ensure you are logged in to your VPS as the root user, and run the following:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

1. Install GNOME:

   ```
   apt-get install gnome-desktop-environment
   ```
2. Install required fonts:

   ```
   apt-get install xfonts-100dpi
   apt-get install xfonts-100dpi-transcoded
   apt-get install xfonts-75dpi
   apt-get install xfonts-75dpi-transcoded
   apt-get install xfonts-base
   ```
3. Install TightVNCServer:

   ```
   apt-get install tightvncserver
   ```
4. Start TightVNCServer for the first time, it will copy config files and prompt you for a password:

   ```
   tightvncserver :1
   ```
5. Stop the VNC server, so we can continue to configure it:

   ```
   tightvncserver -kill :1
   ```
6. Edit the xstartup file:

   ```
   vi ~/.vnc/xstartup
   ```

   Press "A" to enter edit mode. Replace the contents of the file with the following (or edit to match):

   ```
   /bin/shxrdb $HOME/.Xresources xsetroot -solid grey x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" & # x-window-manager & gnome-session &
   ```

   Press ESC, type `:wq`, then press enter to save and close the file.
7. Start the VNC server with your desired resolution:

   ```
   tightvncserver -geometry 1024x768 :1
   ```

You can now access your server's remote GNOME desktop with a desktop VNC client. Enter your server's main IP address, Port 1 (or 5901, alternately), and the password you set earlier to connect to the desktop.

Use this Program : https://www.realvnc.com/download/viewer/