# Getting my ubuntu server running

Tags: gui, 16.10

I have a headless ubuntu server that I have no physical access to but have root privileges via ssh/terminal. I am not at all good command line and would like to install a gui for remote access. I'm running ubuntu 16.10 minimal. I run  the sudo command to install ubuntu desktop and after it is finished I can't figure out what to do. How do I open up a graphic user interface after this?

Comment: You can't open a GUI over SSH. (Well, technically you can stream a single program, but it's not recommended) You'll need to install VNC and do some port forwarding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect to remote Ubuntu Server GUI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/592253/connect-to-remote-ubuntu-server-gui)

Comment: If you only have ssh access, you might have a look at [X2Go](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php). This does not need additional ports, and even works on slow lines. But instead using 'Unity' or 'Gnome', the desktop should then be XFCE or LXDE.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to install X11 (the Linux GUI for Ubuntu) on your server.  The Ubuntu server does not include installing GUI by default.

You can do this with:

```
$ sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

Now you can run the graphical tools by looking in with ssh's `-X` argument.

```
 $ ssh -X yourserver.com
```

After logging in you can type in the graphic version of the application you wish to run.